Line-break within cell, midrule length and text alignment with \cite in cell
I have some troubles with a table with citations in the cells.


I want the text line-break to be earlier.
The text is not aligned in the centre (horizontal).
The text is not aligned in the centre (vertical) .

Any ideas how I can fix this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} 


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]    
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{2.5cm}
    @{}p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-3cm)/3\relax}
    @{}p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-3cm)/3\relax}
    @{}p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-3cm)/3\relax}}

    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{Quantum Matter}  \\

    &\begin{tabular}[t]{c@{}c@{}}Atomic \\ Structure \end{tabular} 
    &\begin{tabular}[t]{c@{}c@{}}Energy \\ Quantisation \end{tabular} &\begin{tabular}[t]{c@{}c@{}}Light-Matter \\ Interactions \end{tabular} \\


    \makecell{Experiments \\ (haptic) }
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  \\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Welcome! An MWE is necessary.

I've made a new example, does this work?

Almost, but \documentclass{article} should be first in document, missed is booktabs package ...

Done. Thanks for the help! @Zarko

For start: your table width is bigger than \textwidth. Try to use X columns of tabularx, package, instead inserting tables use makecell command ....

Let me spell out my comment:

Table is wider than \textwidth
Why you not use tabularx table if you load this package?
Why you use \tabular in cells? The same effect you cane achieve by use of makecell ...

See, if the following MWE produce what you after:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % for vertical centering
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]    
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{2.5cm} *{4}{X}}
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-4}
    &\multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{Quantum Matter}\\
    &\makecell{Atomic \\ Structure} 
    &\makecell{Energy \\ Quantisation} 
    &\makecell{Light-Matter \\ Interactions} \\

\makecell{Experiments \\ (haptic)}
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


I would add more rules to your table, for example before table body and at end of table ... for example like this:

Addendum:
An alternative, with slightly simpler/shorter code you cen get by use of the tabularray package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} Q[c,m] *{4}{X[c,m]} @{}},
             cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
             cell{1}{2} = {c=3}{}
             }
    \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-4}
    &   Quantum Matter  &   &          \\
    \midrule
    &   {Atomic \\ Structure} 
    &   {Energy \\ Quantisation} 
    &   {Light-Matter \\ Interactions} \\
    \midrule
{Experiments \\ (haptic)}
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  
    & \cite{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,p,q}  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}



Thank you, that did it!

@BFolkers, you are welcome! Just now I addendum with alternative code. you may liked it ...
